# Execute CloudFormation even with empty changeset

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

We have a `CloudFormation` (yaml in our Git), it's downloading config files from S3 using `cfn-hup`. When there is a change in the config files on `s3` we can't just create a new changeset and execute it because the changeSet is empty. `CloudFormation` isn't seeing the changes in the config files on `S3` of course. How can we workaround this?

Comment: You could always create some entry in the `Init` section which you would update when the settings change. A file with the name containing current timestamp. Something to trigger cfn-hup.

Comment: @Marcin thx for the hint. I'll test it, but I'm not sure if it would create a new changeset (since no code inside the template will change).

Comment: I see what you mean. Not sure. Can check though.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround that I just tested that it works has two components:

A dummy template parameter which you can change each time you want to change your `Init` section. Meaning each time you get new config file in s3, e.g.:

```
ConfigUpdateRequired:
    Type: String
    Default: some-value
    Description: Change me when a config changes
```

A dummy file, or env variable, in the `Init` section referencing the parameter, e.g.:

```
files: 
    /tmp/dummyfile: 
      content: !Sub "${ConfigUpdateRequired}"
```

Each time you want to update your config file, you modify the `ConfigUpdateRequired` parameter. This will modify the `/tmp/dummyfile`. `cfn-hup` will then detect changes and will update.

Obviously all this process can be automated by means of `CodePipline`, or any thing that could trigger an update of your stack when the config file in S3 changes and set some new value of `ConfigUpdateRequired`.